# collectionview only downloading one image in cellForItemAtIndexPath

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, alamofire

Here is the code. This is in my `UICollectionViewDataSource` class.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let identifier = "UICollectionViewCell"
    let photo = photos[indexPath.row]
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath) as! PhotoCollectionViewCell
    let url = ImageUploaderAPI.urlForPhotoPath(photoTitle: photo.remoteURL)

    if (photo.image == nil) {
        Alamofire.download(url).downloadProgress { progress in
                print("Download Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
            }
            .responseData { response in
            if let data = response.result.value {
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                photo.image = image!
                cell.updateWithImage(image: image)
                print("Downloaded: " + url.absoluteString)
                collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    } else {
        cell.updateWithImage(image: photo.image)
    }
    return cell
}
```

The `progress.fractionCompleted` is showing that the images are being downloaded, but I'm not sure why none of the images are updating. Is it because of how Alamofire works asynchronously? Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
cell.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    if (photo.image == nil) {
        let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {
            data, response, error in
                if error == nil {
                    if let data = data {
                        let image = UIImage(data: data)

                        print("Downloaded: " + url.absoluteString)

                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            photo.image = image!
                            collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])

                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    print(error)
                }
        }
        dataTask.resume()
    } else {
        cell.updateWithImage(image: photo.image)
    }
    cell.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    cell.activityIndicator.isHidden = true

    return cell
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's 3 possible solutions. The first one is because of background thread issues. Instead of just collectionView.reloadData, try using:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { 
collectionView.reloadData
}﻿
```

Another possible solution is a .resume issue? You might want to try adding .resume like my example below:

```
if (photo.image == nil) {
        Alamofire.download(url).downloadProgress { progress in
                print("Download Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
            }
            .responseData { response in
            if let data = response.result.value {
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                photo.image = image!
                cell.updateWithImage(image: image)
                print("Downloaded: " + url.absoluteString)
                collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }.resume
    } else {
        cell.updateWithImage(image: photo.image)
    }
    return cell
}
```

My 3rd and final solution is to simple get rid of the `if (photo.image == nil) {`

Hope this helps

Comment: Hey, thanks for the thorough answer. I'm realizing now only one image is actually being downloaded, while the rest just seem to be downloaded but the `responseData` callback is never called. Any ideas?